# WiX alternative to implement all components manually?

Tags: file, directory, wix, components

I have to implement a installer which has a lot of files and also a huge directory structure. And to implement all of the required components manually, I have to spend a lot of time in it.

Is there any other, shorter way to accelerate it?

Comment: WiX Toolset has a good rundown of, well, its [tools](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/alltools.html), including a [diagram](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/tools.html). Also, be sure to see the sections on Visual Studio and MSBuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Wix Harvest Tool (Heat)](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html) for automatic .wxs composing. Usage (from [community tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/components-of-a-different-color)):

> **heat dir folder -cg SampleGroup -out SampleGroup.wxs**
>   will harvest the folder specified recursively, creating a Fragment consisting of a
>   ComponentGroup with the name specified with the -cg switch. The group
>   will contain as many components as there are files, each component
>   having a single file inside, as the rules dictate, and will assign
>   uniquely generated component, directory and file identifiers that
>   remain the same when regenerated on the same input set. GUIDs will not
>   be generated (only a placeholder text) unless explicitely instructed
>   to do so by the -gg switch.

There are also tons of answers on SO, just search by 'heat' keyword.